# RuntimeException while httpclient.execute in BackgroundService

Tags: android, service, upload, multipartentity

```
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlString);

        HttpResponse response = null;
        MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        StringBody sb;
        String result = null;

        try {
            sb = new StringBody(json.toString());
            mpEntity.addPart("json", sb);

            httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
            response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                result = RestClient.convertStreamToString(instream);
                Log.i("Read from Server", result);

            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(result == "true"){
            this.stopSelf();
        } else {

        }
```

I get an RuntimeException in my Background Service on:

response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

I don't know why :( I do the same not in a Service and everything's ok, but in Service it throws the exception.

Comment: are you sure that urlString is not null?

Comment: Yes all Variables are correct initialized. I've forgot to post that. String urlString = xxx;

Comment: t18935 can you post your logcat?

Comment: I can't find anything about that error in Logcat. Sry. In my virtual Device there are no comments and with my real device there's only some other logs...

Comment: Juhu found out the exception in Log. Sry I was a little bit stupid :)

Comment: Got it!!!! The upload was in the Main Thread!